# ASP.Net Core app: *sometimes* blocked by CORS policy in MSVS debugger (iisexpress); works OK when deployed to IIS7

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, cors, iis-express

I have a bunch of different versions of the same ASP.NET Core app.  My workstation has MSVS 2019. My DEV and PROD servers are Windows Server 2012/IIS7.

The app has been around for years.  It's *NOT* doing anything to explicitly enable CORS. It's *NOT* calling Services.AddCors(), app.UseCors(), policy.WithOrigins(), [EnableCors]  or anything like that.

Most of the time, it "just works".

But *SOMETIMES* (like now), I get a CORS error trying to access FontAwesome when I run in the MSVS 2019 debugger:

> Chrome developer tools console:
>
> ```
> Access to CSS stylesheet at 'https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css' from origin 'https://localhost:44342' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
> ```

When the problem occurs, it's *ONLY* on my workstation in the MSVS 2019 debugger (iiexpress).  It *NEVER* occurs on any of the PROD or DEV servers.

The baffling part is that - as far as I can tell - "nothing changed".  My projects all worked yesterday.  But they're all getting the CORS error on FA CSS today. And the remote IIS servers ... running the same app ... work fine ... in the same browser!

Here's the header from one of the "bad" pages:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js" integrity="sha256-4iQZ6BVL4qNKlQ27TExEhBN1HFPvAvAMbFavKKosSWQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/gijgo@1.9.13/js/gijgo.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/gijgo@1.9.13/css/gijgo.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.25/sorting/datetime-moment.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

I *DON'T* want to modify the app (if I can avoid it), simply because I don't want to risk breaking code that's been around "forever".

I'd *LOVE* to figure out what could possibly be changing in my workstation's environment, so I can "fix" it.

Or maybe I can just use a different link to FontAwesome?

Q: Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `crossorigin="anonymous"` in the `<link>` element causes the browser to load the stylesheet with a CORS request. Without that attribute, stylesheets can be loaded from any origin without CORS.

Perhaps removing the attribute is a workaround for you, because `fontawesome.com` really seems to sporadically omit the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in CORS requests (and also the `Content-Type` header). I could not find a pattern in this.

Comment: Beautiful - thank you.  You provided a couple of useful insights (the significance of "anonymous", and the fact that Fontawesome.com behaves differently at different times/with different versions).  Deeply appreciated - thank you for a thoughtful, knowledgeable response!

Answer (score -1):

**WORKAROUND:**

1. This link describes the basic problem - but I wasn't able to get any useful information from "curl":

- https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/17402
- C:\Windows\System32\curl.exe: curl 7.79.1 (Windows) libcurl/7.79.1 Schannel

  **Result:** "Blank" - no "curl" output whatsoever...

2. I was able to work around the problem by changing all my ASP.Net layouts:

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
   ```

   To this:

   ```
   @*<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">*@
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.11.2/css/all.css" />
   ```

   **Result:** It worked:

   No CORS errors; FontAwesome icons are successfully displaying on MSVS.  Again.

Q: ???WHY???

Q: Any suggestions for how I can troubleshoot exactly what was wrong with the first FA link?

- Why did it work "yesterday"... but started failing "today"?
- Why does it *ALWAYS* work on Windows/IIS7 (http) but *SOMETIMES* fails on MSVS/iisexpress (https/localhost)?

*SOMETHING* from the client request and/or client environment definitely affects whether or not that particular FA server decides to block the request.  I'd definitely like to better understand "what".

Q: Any thoughts/suggestions/further troubleshooting tips?